# Docker-Machine creation failing

Tags: docker, installation

I am trying to create a docker-machine in my windows 10 Enterprise machine.
I am creating using driver **hyperv** but the machine creation is failing with error **Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: OS type not recognized**

```
>>docker-machine create --driver hyperv loc-machine1
```

[image]

I can see the loc-machine1 under **docker-machine ls**
But while trying to communicate from local client **docker-machine env loc-machine1** ,its throwing error

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: 
There was an error validating certificates for host " 
[fe80::215:5dff:fe17:100c]:2376": dial tcp [fe80::215:5dff:fe17:100c]:2376: 
connectex: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs 
[name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might stop 
running containers.
```

Tried **regenerate-certs** but its not working.

Docker version :- 17.03.1-ce

Answer (score 0):

As described in [docker troubleshooting documentation](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/faqs/troubleshoot/), you can try :

- Regenerate certificates then restart docker host.

or

- Create a new docker-machine

Comment: did you try to remove the existing docker-machine and create a new one?

Comment: Yes but still failing.